# Is a surjective morphism $V \to U$ quasi-compact and quasi-separated, if $V, U$ are quasi-compact and $U$ is affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, descent

In Olsson's *Algebraic spaces and stacks* there is the following lemma:

> **Lemma 1.1.6** *Let $f: X \to Y$ be a flat morphism of locally noetherian schemes that is locally of finite type (or more generally, $f$ is a fppf morphism without $X$ and $Y$ being locally noetherian), and let $Y = \bigcup_i U_i$ be an open affine cover. Then for each $i$ there is a Zariski covering $f^{-1}(U_i) = \bigcup_j V_{ij}$ with $V_{ij}$ quasi-compact and $f(V_{ij}) = U_i$.*

When this is applied, Olsson writes that the restricted morphism $f_{ij} = f|_{V_{ij}}: V_{ij} \to U_i$ is now quasi-compact and quasi-separated. Why is that the case? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Quasi-compactness is not so bad - you can check it on any affine open cover by [tag 01K4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01K4), so since $V_{ij}$ is quasi-compact by assumption you can take the cover $\{U_i\}$. I'm a little stumped on quasi-separatedness at the moment - taking $Y=\Bbb A^\infty$ and $X$ two copies of $Y$ glued along the complement of the origin, it seems like the claim might fail? Or else I've made another mistake...

Comment: @KReiser I think you are correct that this gives a counterexample. Thanks for your help, I will discuss this with my professor.